# How do I delete my account on ai.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support

I wrote a question a couple of weeks ago which was blocked without any explanation except a standard text "This post is about specific software, hardware, datasets, or pre-trained models."

The question made ZERO mention of any particular software, hardware, datasets or pre-trained models.

Instead of expressing my disregard for this way of treating people, I just want to have my sub-account deleted permanently.

How can I remove my sub-account on **ai.stackexchange.com** only? I also want to have it deleted from ai.meta.stackexchange.com as well, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry you feel that way. Instructions for how to delete your account may be found [on this page of the Help Center](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow those instructions. Instead of being sorry I feel this way, you should consider doing something about the site policies or at least make moderators substantiate why they tag a question as being too stupid or too lame or too much of a waste of bytes.

Comment: @frodeborli I assume you are referring to [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/36443/1641). Note that no moderators were actually involved in closing (or deleting) that particular post. It was voted to be closed by three non-moderator members of the community, with as reason "This post is about specific software, hardware, datasets, or pre-trained models." I looked at the question, and it indeed looks like it's essentially asking for recommendations for tools/software, which is [not on topic on our site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Well, the question is not about specific software. It is not asking for recommendations, and it is not asking for pre-trained models. It is asking for the *existence* of tools to experiment with AI which is in fact **not specifically** made for any particular programming environment. 

I strongly disagree with this site's policy of maintaining a barrier to keep out newcomers by deeming their question as *too uneducated*. The chosen network name 'AI' is MUCH TOO broad, since the site policy seems restricted to an extremely narrow academic part of the field of AI. @dennis-soemers

Comment: @frodeborli It's not at all a matter of such questions being considered "too uneducated" or "stupid" or "lame" or anything like that. They're simply deemed to be beyond/outside the scope of this site. More appropriate sites may include e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/ or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. If you like it's also possible to debate what should or should not be on topic in a new meta post right here (not in extended comments), dedicated to that topic, but then please search and check out previous posts on that topic throughout the past years first.